# GOLANG load JWK (JSON Web Keys), from memory not loading from a URL ? Fetch

Tags: go, jwt

I'm using "github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwk" to Validate Jason Web Tokens (JWT). https://github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx

The JWK Library has a great function to load keys from a URL, but this would be running in a serverless environment, so I want to cache the keys rather than fetching them like this:

```
set, err := jwk.Fetch(keyUrl)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to load them directly, or create them from the keys I already have.

The keys are the JSON format.

```
{"keys":
[{"alg":"RS256","e":"AQAB","n":"jqm5oX5Vth4JW1gZQHywIki2beYCgBSL-
EYlefDUlI6SShtEKfi-vWYbFh2pNNUAE4NHuYpYP-
FG1uRSKs6WK2k6KMB2Hyx3hBkWyu7Aqo_pb1WItkPSZS-AWOMp4N-
```

I just can't find an example of how to do this. There must be a way

Comment: Have you tried [jwk.Parse](https://godoc.org/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwk#Parse)?

Comment: Yes, I got the Parse to work if I use the jwk.Fetch method to load the Keys from a URL. I'm trying to figure out how to get it working if I load the keys from a string or array of bytes, rather than loading from a URL.

Comment: there is a jwk.Parse(buf []byte) https://github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/blob/master/jwk/jwk.go#L109 and a jwk.ParseString(string) https://github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/blob/master/jwk/jwk.go#L135. do you have code that uses those and does not work as described?

Comment: I reached out to the author of the library. in parallel. What I'm trying to do is load key from a string, rather than pulling the keys from a URL.  I think the call would look something like this: set, err := jwk.New(My_JSON_String) ... I just can't find an example of how to do it.

Comment: So far two people have tried to tell you how to do it and you seem to be ignoring them and restating the problem. https://godoc.org/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwk#Parse takes the key contents instead of a URL. That is the method you want to use.

Comment: Sorry guys, dooh, got wires crossed in my brain, I didn't realize there was a jwk.parse function. Worked like a champ once I realized what you were suggesting. This was exactly what I needed: set, err := jwk.ParseString(`{"keys":[{"alg":"RS256"

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else get's stuck on this, although I think it's unlikely, and thank you Stephen and Jonah for your patience.

jwk.Parse was exactly what I needed. There is even an option for a string.

```
set, err := jwk.ParseString(`{"keys":[{"alg":"RS256","e":"AQAB","n":"jqm5oX5Vth4JW1gZQHywIki2beYCgBSL-EYlefDUlI6SShtEKfi-vWYbFh2pNNUAE4NHuYpYP-FG1uRSKs6WK2k6KMB2Hyx3hBkWyu7Aqo_pb1WItkPSZS-AWOMp4N-ENPGyNQ4u2ill17ZwBKt1wgDvdaWpNaqPEcSaUNSXA7ZD5scFFnZt36r6crhgK7vHXChhXU3nlKEN2OwFdyEGdX01l-HxgPk0HPIfnUyYxuGI_CL-7aV_rf3KY4uw6yNfEO0jom0NZ-I8F1NzpbaDxj4hD4xlDZIQI9PxLq4nAtb4ZVQC1xhnRv-uufs9Wa4XFjs6jJSWGcWV1Z7K5HmMaw","kid":"tNtnDgeXepbf2NZlVjzKGdtPU9mnOidtw0puo3s-_8Y","kty":"RSA","use":"sig"},{"alg":"RS256","e":"AQAB","n":"o_CYYN5Lo9XuCRADNxqDTVolcWshv7LD7EmwFCvtbdHErvfOQPHyAFMLMDKracToe2Rg7cBihYC_wgHRItXAgxAM6P7mNT_DvbLpp2HtbMtmYLtWyGqHJsJQE9gNSOMsxEugxq9lpGjROiU2nZm7TZ-QwVV-F7dfBl0NBVy5oFbTCRUDxFcKOr_zh3xK-fRIsJbqbB4VPt8IhA_GjvjyoMlH0pfhoRqDMWk8vLXHhRxYlT5bZP1PDulFMGGO8KH7Cvh4D0cZE9mSiUFyVlDDzCbAH88a0TAGYkqERdVfHBYaTsCCseBqsvUoqbdzQwd2fOLf-N0jpSdNMNxHGNwl3w","kid":"ddPUDDyUpH2N5wGSXvnqQZy-OmTFSVu5PYansjpsoAs","kty":"RSA","use":"sig"}]}`)
```